# Thin doesn't output when fork/exec-ed from Ruby

Tags: ruby, exec, stdout, pipe, thin

I'm trying to run `thin start 2>&1` in a subprocess by running `fork`/`exec`, and I'm reassigning STDOUT to a pipe so I can feed output through.

However, I don't get any output when Thin starts successfully. When it errors, I get the output in the wrong order—error text first, then the standard Thin startup messages.

I copied the code from Foreman, which handles this correctly. Any idea what's going on?

Code:

```
reader, writer = IO.pipe
pid = fork do
  Process.setpgrp
  trap("INT", "IGNORE")
  $stdout.reopen writer
  reader.close
  exec("thin start 2>&1")
end
Process.detach pid
until reader.eof?
  puts reader.gets
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data sent to `$stdout` isn't printed immediately -- it's buffered. On the other hand, `$stderr` isn't buffered and when you write to it you see results immediately. Let's see a minimal example.

```
STDOUT.puts :stdout
STDERR.puts :stderr
```

Save it as `test.rb` and replace `thin start` with `ruby test.rb`. Most probably `stdout` will be printed after `stderr`. In order to fix it we'll have to use the [`IO#sync=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) method

```
STDOUT.sync = true
STDOUT.puts :stdout
STDERR.puts :stderr
```

Now `stdout` will be printed synchronously, just as `stderr` is, and the resulting order of printed strings should be the intuitive one.

Initial lack of output from your child Thin process might be caused by the fact that the child isn't flushing data to STDOUT. First piece of data written to STDERR causes STDOUT to flush. Try adding `STDOUT.sync = true` somewhere in your application's or Thin's sources and see whether it helped.

See also a discussion on ruby-forum.com titled [capture output in real time](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/152548).

Comment: Thanks! After trying the solutions discussed in that thread, I've settled on using PTY, which tricks the child process into line-buffered mode.